# Relation - elementary set theory proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Claim: Suppose $R \subseteq M x M$ is a relation on a set M such that $R \subseteq  R^{-1}$ and R is symmetric .Then $R^{-1} \subseteq R$ also.

I had:

Suppose R is a relation on set M such that $R \subseteq R^{-1}$. 
Then if R is symmetric $R = R^{-1}$.  If $R \subseteq R^{-1}$ then by definition $R^{-1} \subseteq R$.

Is this a valid response?

Comment: NOW it makes sense. Frankly,I had to see what the others' responses were to figure out what the heck you were asking.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Your edit actually changed the question. The question is to simply prove that $R^{-1}\subset R$ given the conditions, **not** to show that it is symmetric iff $R^{-1} \subset R$, which is trivially true by definition. In effect, this proof shows that $R\subset R^{-1}$ is sufficient for $R$ to be symmetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can assert that $R$ is symmetric in order to prove that $R$ is symmetric.

Start with $R \subset R^{-1}$; this implies that if $(x,y) \in R$, then $(x,y) \in R^{-1}$. But this implies that $(y,x) \in R$ by definition of $R^{-1}$.

Now consider an arbitrary $(u,v) \in R^{-1} \Rightarrow (v,u) \in R$. Then $(v,u) \in R^{-1}$ so that $(u,v) \in R$. Thus, $R^{-1} \subset R$.

Comment: Beat me to it-it wasn't even clear to me that THAT'S what the OP was trying to prove!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
(a,b)\in R^{-1} &\Rightarrow (b,a) \in R\\
&\Rightarrow (b,a)\in R^{-1} \quad (\text{because} \  R\subseteq R^{-1}) \\
&\Rightarrow (a,b)\in R\\
\end{align}

Comment: Uh-and this is assuming R is symmetric? Because it sure isn't clear from the way the question is stated that this is what he/she wanted to prove!

Comment: The question is asking for a proof of $R^{-1}\subseteq R$. It is implicit that symmetry is not required, because it has not been used.

Comment: Uh-can we really state that for every relation, $R= R^{-1}$? Because that's ultimately what the conclusion is and that seems very bizarre to me.If R is symmetric, then yes,that makes perfect sense.

Comment: That's not the conclusion. The assumption was that $R\subseteq R^{-1}$.

Comment: Then what was he trying to prove? That R was symmetric? I think the op is trying to prove R is symmetric iff $R^{-1}$ = R and I edited the question accordingly. I couldn't make heads or tails of it how the OP stated it.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Then you should ask OP to clarify what he means. The question as first appeared was to prove $R^{-1}\subseteq R$ assuming the inverse holds. There was no mention of symmetry in the question.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 besides, the accepted answer is basically what I said. There is no mention of symmetry in that answer.